# Python find tag in XML using wildcard

Tags: python, xml, lxml, wildcard

I have this line in my python script:

```
url = tree.find("//video/products/product/read_only_info/read_only_value[@key='storeURL-GB']")
```

but sometimes the storeURL-GB key changes the last two country code letters, so I am trying to use something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
url = tree.find("//video/products/product/read_only_info/read_only_value[@key='storeURL-\.*']")
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably try `.xpath()` and `starts-with()`:

```
urls = tree.xpath("//video/products/product/read_only_info/read_only_value[starts-with(@key, 'storeURL-')]")
if urls:
    url = urls[0]
```